# store string in array using scanner

Tags: java

I have a file in path d:\input.txt 
I want get this path from user with Scanner class
Here is my code but i recevie ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException
Why?

```
if(args.length != 0)
        {
            readerWriter.readFile(args[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Plese enter the path of your file");                
            Scanner filePath = new Scanner(System.in);
            args[0] = filePath.next();
            readerWriter.readFile(args[0]);
        }
```

Comment: how did you run this ?

Comment: @mahdieh at which line you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't using array here `args[0] = filePath.next();` because your array is not initialized and give ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, try:

`String file = filePath.next();
   readerWriter.readFile(file);`

Comment: @mahdieh If an Answer provided some value, please **give the Answer an upvote** (click the upward triangle if viewing in a web browser). If an Answer solves your problem or resolves your Question, **accept the Answer** (click the big empty checkmark appearing below the downward triangle, if in a browser). Acceptance signals to other readers that you consider the Question closed/resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if `args.length` is 0.

You should do

```
if(args.length != 0)
        {
            readerWriter.readFile(args[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Plese enter the path of your file");                
            Scanner filePath = new Scanner(System.in);
            readerWriter.readFile(filePath.next());
        }
```

and not use `args[0]` in else.

Program will go in `else` block if `args.length == 0` and `args[0] = filePath.next();` will give `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

Comment: have you looked at the first line?

Comment: Yes program will go in else if `args.length == 0` and `args[0] = filePath.next();` will give `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException `.

Comment: oops, my bad, forgot to take my coffee this morning :)

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, if

```
args.length == 0
```

you cannot access

```
args[0]
```

So you have to change the lines,

```
args[0] = filePath.next();
readerWriter.readFile(args[0]);
```

into

```
String myPath = filePath.next();
readerWriter.readFile(myPath);
```